# Replace parts of a sentence with another variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace

I am trying to iteratively match the `image_id` variable with the parts of another string saved under `name in zip_file.namelist()`. If the `image_id` variable does not match with the `(\d+)` portion in the `name` string, then the digit `(\d+)` will be replaced with the `image_id` variable. However, I am unable to do so. Please see my current code below:

```
this_folder = dirname("C:/Users/xxxxx/Documents/xxxx/")
doc_path = join(this_folder, 'Sample - Copy v1.docx')    
doc = docx.Document(doc_path)

def iter_block_items(parent):
     if isinstance(parent, Document):
         parent_elm = parent.element.body
     elif isinstance(parent, _Cell):
         parent_elm = parent._tc
     elif isinstance(parent, _Row):
         parent_elm = parent._tr
     else:
         raise ValueError("something's not right")

     for child in parent_elm.iterchildren():
         if isinstance(child, CT_P):
             yield Paragraph(child, parent)
         elif isinstance(child, CT_Tbl):
             yield Table(child, parent)

found_images = []

for block in iter_block_items(doc):
     if isinstance(block, Paragraph):
         # Read a paragraph.
         if block.text != "":
             print(block.text)
             Sheet1.write(index_row, 0, block.text)
             index_row += 1

         # Indicate if an image is found in the paragraph.
         if 'graphicData' in block._p.xml:
             xml = str(block._p.xml)
             index_column = 0

             for image_id in re.findall(r'<wp:docPr id="(\d+)"', XML):
                 #intending to paste to another Excel workbook later on:
                 found_images.append((index_row, index_column, image_id))
                 index_column += 1

             image_paragraphs.append(block)
             index_row += 1
found_images   
     with ZipFile(doc_path) as zip_file:
         zipped_images = {}
     
         #sourcing for images in the document (.docx):
         for name in zip_file.namelist():
             if name.startswith('word/media/'):
                 m = re.fullmatch('word/media/image(\d+)\.\w+', name)

                 if m:
                    zipped_images[m.group(0)] = name   
                    #print(name) 
                    #output: word/media/image1.jpeg

                 

         for index_row, index_column, image_id in found_images:
             #print(image_id)
             #output: 18
             if image_id not in name:
                    regex = r"(?<=word/media/image)\d+(?=\.\w+$)"
                    name = re.sub(regex, image_id, name)
                    #print(name)
                    #output: customXml/_rels/item4.xml.rels
                    #intended output: word/media/image18.jpeg

                    #Error occurs here:
                    with zip_file.open(zipped_images[image_id]) as image_file:
                    #output: KeyError: '18'
                        image_data = BytesIO(image_file.read())

                    Sheet1.insert_image(index_row, index_column, 'image%s' % image_id, {'image_data': image_data})
```

Could anyone tell me where I went wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Please update the question to include `zipped_images` as well as the original value of `name`.

Comment: Hi @HampusLarsson its a very long code....so i thought snippets of it would be better. But alright, thanks, I'll add it in

Comment: NO, minimal, as in, as few lines of code as possible to still have the error you're reporting.

Comment: @HampusLarsson oh ok, got it! Let me try to do that!

Comment: I think you also have to set name again to the result `name=name.replace` and use `re.sub` instead. Do you want to replace all the numbers to 18?

Comment: @Thefourthbird if i set name again as the result, the output is just `18` instead of my intended output: `word/media/image18.jpeg`. No, not all the numbers, for each iteration where the digits in `name` does not match `image_id`, it will be replaced with the `image_id` value.

Comment: Perhaps something like this https://ideone.com/xIw0Gl

Comment: @Thefourthbird Can you see my updated post? I had tried to apply what you had done to my code but i still get the same output: `customXml/_rels/item4.xml.rels` instead of my intended output.

Comment: Try using `name=re.sub(regex, image_id, name)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird hi, sorry i was away from my work desktop. but yes, I tried that and the same error still occurs. I'm not sure what went wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.sub` like this:

```
if image_id not in name:
   re.sub('\d', image_id, name)
```

Comment: I tried this and i got the `error: bad escape \d at position 0`